# NestJs/microservices Kafka - Consume messages per batch

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs, kafkajs

I'm looking for consuming messages per batch with nestjs/microservices by using the decorator @MessagePattern('topic') or something equivalent.
I would like to fetch multiple records together, process them and then, send the commit of the latest record when all the batch has been processed.
I used before batch listeners in Spring Kafka to do this.

Should I use kafkajs or is there a way with nestjs/microservices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think nestJs is using kafkaJs under the hood, which does batching even if you're processing with `eachMessage`. However if you need more direct control over the batch you'd use https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#a-name-each-batch-a-eachbatch.